# SqlDataSource Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The questions seems to be easy but unfortunately the command I'm using here is not working for me.

I'm having this command line inside my webform

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
  ConnectionStrings:dmax0913_4Sem_18ConnectionString %>" 
  ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT [Strength], [Intelligence], [Charm], [Talent] FROM [Male] 
  WHERE [Male.ID] = [User.ID]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Basically I want to display in a gridview the "Strenght" , "Intelligence" , "Charm" and "Talent" which are stored in a table named "Male" where the ID of the table is equal to the ID of another table named User.

Comment: If you are using MySql try removing '[' and ']'

Comment: Is your database MySQL, or is it Microsoft's SQL Server? Because the Provider Name you specified is for MS SQL Server, but you tagged this question as MySQL. Also, are you getting an error message? What is it?

Comment: Yes my database is MS SQL Server and I'm not getting any error message I'll fix the tag , my bad

Answer (score 0):

You need `Inner Join` here:-

```
SelectCommand ="SELECT [Strength], [Intelligence], [Charm], [Talent] FROM [Male] 
INNER JOIN [User] ON [Male.ID] = [User.ID]"
```

Comment: This alone won't be enough to fix the issue, assuming that he's using MySQL as the question is tagged.

Comment: @mason - You're correct, I just saw the provider name. Will update based on OP's feedback otherwise delete it;)

Comment: Apologies for my incorrect tag, I'm not using MySQL but MS SQL Server

Comment: @dtmnn - Okay. So did this fixed your issue?

Comment: No , I'm having this error now.  "Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name "Male.ID".

Comment: @dtmnn - These are pretty basics, you should refer to some tutorials. From `Male` & `User` tables you need to specify the column name which actualls `joins` them. Here i thought it's ID but if you want real solution please post the table structure of both.